# how Value type works in enum?

Tags: scala

what's a diff between these two snippets

```
  object Main extends Enumeration {

    val first : String = "Thriller"
    val second : String = "Horror"
    val third : String = "Comedy"
    val fourth : String = "Romance"

    // Main Method
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
      println(s" Movie Genres = ${Main.first}")
    }
  }
```

And

```
object Main extends Enumeration
{
    type Main = Value
     
    // Assigning values
    val first = Value("Thriller")
    val second = Value("Horror")
    val third = Value("Comedy")
    val fourth = Value("Romance")
     
    // Main method
    def main(args: Array[String])
    {
        println(s"Main Movie Genres = ${Main.values}")
    }
}
```

what benefit am getting by using `type Main = Value` in second code snippet ? I'm struggling to understand this even after reading alot online. Please share any simple understanding if possible.

Because in Java when we define this below code, all values (HEARTS, DIAMOND etc) are of CardSuit type, so can't we say that (first, second etc) are of `Main` type ?

```
enum CardSuit{
    HEARTS,
    DIAMONDS,
    CLUBS,
    SPADES,
}
```

Last is, Is there any way I could have more than 2 attributes assign to any enum's constants in scala ? For example `val first = Value("Thriller", "movie, "london", "production")`

Comment: `Enumeration` was a bad idea, nobody uses it. Just use a sealed trait + case objects.

Comment: Just switch to Scala 3 and use `enum`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enumeration used private constructors and other tricks to:

- define type `Value` within your `object` that you extended with `Enumeration`
- limited constructors so that they could only be called from within your object
- make these constructors do side-effects so that each new value would append itself to the mutable list (which isn't mutable from outside)

This approach has several issues:

1. when you do `object MyEnum extends Enumeration` your enumerations will NOT be defined as `MyEnum` type, but as `MyEnum.Value`
2. if you want to use `MyEnum` as the name of enumeration, you have to use type alias `type MyEnum = MyEnum.Value` or `type MyEnum = Value`
3. however the type of companion will still be `MyEnum.Value.type` instead of `MyEnum.type`. Aliases creating `MyEnum.MyEnum` and `MyEnum.MyEnum.type` are just silly
4. each value is of the same type, so type level programming options are quite limited
5. you cannot customize `Value`: let it inherit your type, add some field, store something else than String, not store anything...

Points 1. and 2. are the reasons people did the type aliasing. All 5 were the reasons people moves to sealed traits

```
sealed trait MyEnum extends Product with Serializable
object MyEnum {
  case object One extends MyEnum
  case object Two extends MyEnum
  case object Three extends MyEnum
}
```

they work better with pattern matching, derivation, it is easier to customize them (you just add things to common trait/common abstract class), etc.

In Scala 3 it got simplified to

```
enum MyEnum:
  case One, Two, Three
```

All in all, there is virtually 0 reasons to use `Enumeration` other than legacy code.

Comment: Also, the fact that, IIRC _(if I am wrong please correct me)_, `Enumeration` does not have exhaustive checking which is a big no-no for an enum.

Comment: It has all sorts of limitation for pattern matching, it merely lets you check that value of of type `Value` and that you instance match some named instance. Exhaustive checks, subtypes, extracting values, all off the table AFAIR.